# The workstation doesn't switch to synchronous group policy processing on restart

Tags: group-policy

The workstation is running Windows 8.1 and joined to the domain. There are a few group policies that deploy software. "Always wait for the network at computer startup and logon" setting is disabled. Software deployment has used to take 1 or 2 logons to apply the changes, as expected.

But something happened, and now I can't get software deployment to apply the changes at all. rsop.msc says: "Software Installation did not complete policy processing because a system restart is required for the settings to be applied.  Group Policy will attempt to apply the settings the next time the computer is restarted." Restarting has no effect: the group policies are still processed in asynchronous mode, and rsop.msc says just the same. Rejoining the domain doesn't help. No error is in the Event log.

The question is what is the switch / the flag that tells Windows to enable synchronous processing of the group policies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was the startup policy processing timeout: the default value of 30 s isn't sometimes enough. Setting "Specify startup policy processing wait time" policy (Computer Configuration - Policies - Administrative Templates - System - Group Policy) to 120 s fixed the issue.